# MariaDB vs Drizzle vs Percona Server vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, percona, mariadb, drizzle

I've been a MySQL user for a long time now. I'd like to start using all the different variations between the most popular forks. The problem is that I can't find any good comparison between them, and I'll end up just trying all of them. My concerns are in terms of production, because I won't experiment with all these forks in production.

Have you ran any of MySQL forks in production?

What are the advantages? What are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 19):

Basically:

- Percona Server - MySQL plus 10% for "real production"
- MariaDB - a "drop in replacement" fork that aims for compatibility while adding own features
- Drizzle - a database server that speaks the same network protocol and is largely DML compatible with MySQL, sharing some code ancestry.

Disclaimer: I worked for MySQL AB and Sun on MySQL, am a core Drizzle developer (since the start) and am currently Director of Server Development at Percona and I count many MariaDB and Oracle MySQL developers as friends (and long time colleagues).

If you don't want to change any application code at all: that's the choice between MariaDB, Percona Server and Oracle MySQL.

If you're wanting a database server that is designed for cloud like environments, is modular and entirely an open source project: go check out Drizzle.

Comment: That being said, are there any benchmarks to differentiate the different dbs?